# OnDestroy() is being called after onCreate() when I start Activity

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I am updating the local database in `onDestroy()` of activity A. Activity B is depends on the local DB which is updated in `onDestroy()` of activity A.

My problem is that whenever I start Activity B and finish Activity A `onDestroy()` of activity A is being called after `onCreate()` of Activity B. Due to this issue I am losing the data stored after destroying Activity A.

How do I fix this issue?

Activity A

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    //After retrieving User data
    //inside onclicklistener
    someButton.setOnClickLister( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
              finish();
              startActivity(this,FamilyInfoActivity.class);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    localJson.setStatus(status);
    localDBUtil.setLocalJson(this,localJson,connectionId);
    super.OnDestroy();
}
```

Activity B

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    localJson = localDBUtil.getLocalJson(this,connectionId);
    
}
```

Comment: Please share some code from ActivityA & ActivityB so we can offer help like this is way to abstract.

Comment: what's preventing you to also update the database right before you start Activity B?

Comment: What you're seeing is the [expected Activity lifecycle order](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#coordinating-activities) for moving from one activity to another. As @IvoBeckers suggested, you could update the database right before starting the next activity.

Comment: I want to capture the data even if the user closes the app (to resume the registration process) This is why I am updating the DB inside onDestroy.

Comment: @PritamPawade What DB are you using? I assume the call to the db is async and it takes time to finish, you are destroying the activity before that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rely on the timing of `onDestroy()` to save your changes. You should save changes in `onPause()` which is the only lifecycle method that is guaranteed to be called.

Also, if you want to pass data from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB`, you can use one of the following methods:

- Store data in a file
- Store data in an SQLite database
- Store data in `SharedPreferences`
- Put the data in "extras" in the `Intent` you use to launch `ActivityB` (only if the amount of data is not too large)

Answer (score -1):

Please remove `finish()` in `onCreate`. `Finish` is destroying your `Activity` that's why `onDestroy` is being called

Comment: onDestroy() is being called after onCreate() of Activity B is my problem. also, I want to destroy Activity A.

Comment: Your flow is wrong. If you want to start `ActivityB` in `onCreate` that means you don't want `ActivityA` then why you are starting `activityA`. You can do your work before starting activity in `AsyncTask` or using `RxJava` after that directly start `ActivityB`

Comment: I need activity A I and it have 800+ lines of code. Here I pasted only the problem. This is not the actual code.

Comment: Your `ActivityA` contains this code `@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    finish();
    startActivity(this,FamilyInfoActivity.class);
    
}`, onCreate method includes `finish()` call. Right?

Comment: If you are finishing activity in `oncreate` how the processing will be completed?

Comment: Actually, the code is complicated, and finish() is being called inside onClick listener. This is just to explain my problem.

Comment: @PritamPawade Its better to run code `finish();
    startActivity(this,FamilyInfoActivity.class);`  in `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask ` after doing DB Processing in `doInBackground` so that your db changes are saved before starting next activity.